# Return 2 values from a function - java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to make a list of online users and offline users.

But since I can't return 2 arrayLists from a function, how can I do this?

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loggedUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> getLoggedUsers() {
    Map<String,User> users = User.getUsers().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUsername, Function.identity()));
    List<User> onlineUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String username : activeUsers.getUsers()) {
        User user = users.get(username);
        if(user != null) {
            onlineUsers.add(user);
        }
    }
    return onlineUsers;
}
```

Now I need the rest (not online users) and put mark them as offline

AJAX

```
 //get loggedUsers
$.ajax({
    url: '/loggedUsers',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (loggedUsers) {
        console.log(loggedUsers);    
    }
});
```

Comment: create a new Class with 2 lists in it for offline and online

Comment: Add a boolean to your class object which indicates if they are offline or online.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an object where two property of 2 arrayLists

```
ResponseObject
{
   List<User> onlineUsers; 
   List<User> offlineUsers;
}
```

Return this object as response.

in javascript response, you will get this 2 arrayLists

```js
 //get loggedUsers
$.ajax({
    url: '/loggedUsers',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (Users) {
        console.log(Users.onlineUsers);
        console.log(Users.offlineUsers);   
    }
});
```